# Are there any Buddhist charities or organisations funding education in Buddhist studies?

Tags: academic-buddhism

Further to answers to [this question](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/27101/are-there-any-higher-education-opportunities-in-buddhism), I am looking for any Buddhist organizations or charities that may offer to fund for pursuing a higher academic education in Buddhism, all over the world.

I searched but I don't really get proper keywords. So if you know any such institution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maitripa College in Portland, Oregon has scholarship opportunities available: https://maitripa.org/event/scholarship-applications-are-available/

Comment: Thank you for the answer. As much as I would like to come to US, the entry requirements are stringent.

Comment: http://www.collegescholarships.org/scholarships/buddhism.htm

https://www.woninstitute.edu/

https://www.buddhanet.net/e-learning/index.htm

https://tricycle.org/magazine/where-to-study/

Answer (score 2):

Please see the [The Robert H. N. Ho Family Foundation Program in Buddhist Studies](https://www.acls.org/programs/buddhist-studies/). It says:

> The American Council of Learned Societies (ACLS) announces the sixth
>   year of an initiative supporting research and teaching in Buddhist
>   studies, funded by The Robert H. N. Ho Family Foundation. In
>   cooperation with the Foundation, ACLS offers an integrated set of
>   fellowship and grant competitions supporting work that will expand the
>   understanding and interpretation of Buddhist thought in scholarship
>   and society, strengthen international networks of Buddhist studies,
>   and increase the visibility of innovative currents in those studies.
>
> **These are global competitions. There are no restrictions as to the location of work proposed, or the citizenship/residence of applicants.
>   The final products of research supported may be in any language.**

In order to qualify for this, you can be doing your studies in any country in any language.

Answer (score 0):

There are no real behind the Buddhas (re-)ligion, the "institution" of his monks, the Sangha. What ever other ways outside the Vinaya and tradition, one should know as corrupt in measures of Dhamma-Vinaya, not able to transport the Sublime Buddhas heritage, simply ways of livelihood and eager tries to make copies and deprive the world of the existence of his heritage.

The Buddhas "economy" is based on goodness with no interest to bind or increase and nurish debts to the world and not tending to leave home and stands.

Dhamma-Vinaya is nothing that can be studied in schools and out of books but requires proper cirumstances so that it is not hurtful at least.

Nothing to fear to get not really enough founded once having joined an upright Sangha and to life exclusively on generosity without objectives and impure motivations toward world but straight to liberation.

If not able to join the Sangha, the Ven. are usually open for serious questions any time. Also this, how ever, requires temporary leaving home and ones stand.

So you may be informed that such ways, either not knowing(aware) or deliberatly organised, are neither proper nor respectful but always "greedy" or "harmwishing" motivated. Be special careful if Monks join such improper undertakings.

There is only one "Buddhist organization" and this is the Sangha of the Buddhas good Bhikkhus. What ever organe else presented, one should know as "fake" and harmful for many.